Push replication server error: The process could not connect to Subscriber
I am trying to set up merge replication with push transactions. I have SQL Server on google server and my local PC, I installed the radmin vpn program, I can connect through SQL Server Management Studio via named instances, both from the local PC to the server and from the server to the local PC, everything works.
I created a publisher and a snapshot:
enter image description here
enter image description here
In the error log I get the following messages:

Error messages:
The process could not connect to Subscriber 'WIN-GGH2H07UGC4'. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20084)
Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL20084
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [1326].  (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 1326)
Get help: http://help/1326
A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 1326)
Get help: http://help/1326
Query timeout expired, Failed Command:  (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 0)
Get help: http://help/0
The merge process failed to execute a query because the query timed out. If this failure continues, increase the query timeout for the process. When troubleshooting, restart the synchronization with verbose history logging and specify an output file to which to write.   > (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 0)
Get help: http://help/0
The subscription to publication 'sync_repl' could not be verified. Ensure that all Merge Agent command line parameters are specified correctly and that the subscription is correctly configured. If the Publisher no longer has information about this subscription, drop and recreate the subscription.  (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147201019)
Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL-2147201019`

Settings are there, port 1433 is open in the firewall. I would also like to mention that one instance of SQL Server runs on port 14333 and another 1433, but the rules in the firewall are open for 14333 and 1433, remote connections are allowed.
What am I doing wrong?

Do you need vpn to connect? Maybe the user running replication doesn't have that vpn running

Yes, I use VPN, I have a task: to start bidirectional replication on a remote server and my local machine, the remote server has a permanent IP, and my local machine is dynamic.

Are you using the port number in your connection details, serverNameOrIpAddress,14333, or are you using the instance name, serverNameOrIpAddress\MSSQLSERVER2022? Using an instance name also requires that the SQL Browser service is running and that it is accessible via udp/1434.

The problem was that the remote server was on port 14333 and it tried to connect to the subscriber on port 14333 and the subscriber was listening to port: 1433 it looks like this is an error, to solve this problem create a subscription with a port where the subscriber listens to port 1433, after the subscription is created, change the port on the sub-subscriber to 14333 as on the remote server and the problem will be solved.

Why are you asking yourself where you should look for the error?

@Dmitro: Please [edit] this answer to only include the solution. If you have a new question, post it as a new question and link back to this question for context—and vice versa. StackOverflow doesn’t work well as, and intended for, asking follow-up questions in answers.
